How to get existing field names for documents?
I have documents with loads of fields:
{
"a1":"v1",
"a2":null,
"f1":"v3",
"f2":"",
"f3":"v3"
}

I would like to get a list of existing fields
for the above the result would be : a1,f1,f3
The closest I came is to specify all the fields by hand into an exists query like this:
"a1_fields": {
        "filter": {
            "exists": {
                "field": "a1"
            }
        }
    } ..etc

this will return :
     "a1_fields": {
            "doc_count": 1
        } ..etc

however I dont want to specify the fields by hand, but using wildcard the result won't contain the breakdowns by the fieldnames:
"all_fields": {
        "filter": {
            "exists": {
                "field": "*"
            }
        }
    } ..etc

So the question is how to get all the existing field names for a set of documents?

field usage stats API can help.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/field-usage-stats.html

Why can't you just get the mapping? Or you do want null fields? Cause mapping might return them

@TusharShahi mapping doesnt mean they are in use

Yes thats what i meant. The title made me feel like you require just the name so thats why.

On _search
On search you can specify in the body of the request fields: ["*"]. This will return all field & value indexed for the current document.
demo
PUT 79250824
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "properties": {
      "a1":{"type":"keyword"},
      "a2":{"type":"keyword"},
      "a3":{"type":"keyword", "index": false}
    }
  }
}

POST 79250824/_bulk
{"index":{}}
{"a1": "v1", "a2": "v2", "a3": "v3"}
{"index":{}}
{"a1": "v1", "a3": "v3"}
{"index":{}}
{"a1": "v1", "a2": null, "a3": "v3"}
{"index":{}}
{"a1": "v1", "new_field": "c2"}


GET 79250824/_search
{
  "query": {"match_all":{}},
  "fields": [
    "*"
  ]
}

You should get per document the fields that have been indexed mapped:
{
  "took": 8,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 4,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "79250824",
        "_id": "Lf-BkZMBD2NlCdx5IRpu",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "a1": "v1",
          "a2": "v2",
          "a3": "v3"
        },
        "fields": {
          "a1": [
            "v1"
          ],
          "a2": [
            "v2"
          ],
          "a3": [
            "v3"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "79250824",
        "_id": "Lv-BkZMBD2NlCdx5IRpu",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "a1": "v1",
          "a3": "v3"
        },
        "fields": {
          "a1": [
            "v1"
          ],
          "a3": [
            "v3"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "79250824",
        "_id": "L_-BkZMBD2NlCdx5IRpu",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "a1": "v1",
          "a2": null,
          "a3": "v3"
        },
        "fields": {
          "a1": [
            "v1"
          ],
          "a3": [
            "v3"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "79250824",
        "_id": "MP-BkZMBD2NlCdx5IRpu",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "a1": "v1",
          "new_field": "c2"
        },
        "fields": {
          "a1": [
            "v1"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}


you still have to somehow aggregate them to come up with a list of fields in use.

Indeed this isn't a perfect solution, but I assume your backend should be able to handle it ?

yepp it would be able, but why return thousends of pieces of list to the backend instead of just making the aggregation on ES side?

Because I don't think this is doable. Or I must have mist understood your question.
